# How to import and use _.sortBy from lodash

Tags: javascript, lodash

I'm trying to use _.sortBy method from lodash by making a code like this :

```
import _sortBy from 'lodash';
var questions = [.......some array....];
questions = _sortBy(questions, 'position');

console.log(questions);
```

The content of console.log(question) is empty. I don't know why, I think I don't know how to load _.sortBy from lodash. I have tried this :

```
questions = _sortBy._.sortBy(questions, 'position')
```

or

```
questions = _.sortBy(questions, 'position')
```

But there is an error `"bundle.js:45504 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'sortBy' of undefined"` or `"Uncaught TypeError: (0 , _jquery2.default)(...).sortable is not a function"`. Also I have read this page : https://lodash.com/docs#sortBy

But I have no idea how to load and use this _.sortBy method. Please help..:)

Note: Sorry for the stupid question if this question is so easy

Comment: `import _sortBy from 'lodash';` here you are importing lodash and not a module in it. it should be `import _ from 'lodash';` and then you can do `_.sortBy`

Comment: If I just use _.sortBy, there is an error show up "Uncaught TypeError: (0 , _jquery2.default)(...).sortable is not a function", seemed that _.sortBy is not loaded... Any clue Mr. Rajesh..?? :)

Comment: Try checking what you are getting in `_sortBy`.

Comment: mmm... Okie... Lemme take a moment.. :)

Comment: Ooowh... It seems cool.. :D 
Thanks Mr. Rajesh.. ;)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In your case, you have two options :

- you can import the entire collection : `import _ from 'lodash';`
  Then you will be able to use it like this : `_.sortBy()`
- However, you can also import specific function. So rather import whole lodash collection, it's better just import lodash's function, especially when you work in production.

So you can do : `import sortBy from 'lodash/sortBy';`

Then you will be able to use it like this : `sortBy()`

Comment: @Hyosoka Poipo Yes, normally you just have to do : `import _ from 'lodash/core';`
If you want, you can create your own [custom package](https://lodash.com/custom-builds)

Answer (score 4):

you can import specific item using curly braces.

**how it works ?**

_ is not exported as default so using like below will throw error.

```
import _ from lodash
```

however you can import everything from lodash in _ using below code

```
import * as _ from 'lodash';
```

but if you want to import specific functions or anything which is exported you can use it like below example

```
import {sortBy} from 'lodash';

var users = [
  { 'user': 'fred',   'age': 48 },
  { 'user': 'barney', 'age': 36 },
  { 'user': 'fred',   'age': 40 },
  { 'user': 'barney', 'age': 34 }
];

sortBy(users, function(o) { return o.user; });
```